# SQL Server - Cannot restore database backup from file on SQL Operations Studio

Tags: sql-server, linux, macos

I'm using SQL Server 2017 Linux in a Docker image on Mac. I want to transfer data from a database on SQL Server for Windows to SQL on Mac. I created .bak backup file in Windows and stored in my Mac's Downloads folder.

I use SQL Operations Studio on my Mac to connect to my SQL-Linux database. When I try to restore from the file, I get directories that does not exist on my Mac, and cannot find my file. How to get to the file on my Downloads in order to restore this backup?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is that any SQL Server backup/restore can only be done to folders which the SQL Server instance has access to. SQL Operations Studio and SSMS will both show a remote file browser over the folders / files visible to the SQL Server instance, not your local machine's folders.

For Docker, the file location is different to a standard Windows / Linux install since by default the file system "inside" the docker container is independent from the file system on the host (mac) machine.

Recommended solution:
- Follow this [docker config doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker) to "Mount a host directory as data volume" - this will let you map a directory on your mac to the docker instance. Then you can copy bak files to that directory and they will be accessible by SQL Server on Docker. The dialogs in SSMS and SQL Operations Studio will now see any files dropped to that location.
- If you follow the [doc on restoring bak files to SQL Server on Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container) you'll guidance on a commandline only workflow if you prefer that.

Comment: Really helpful. I'll give it a try.